# drawing an image on top of another in flutter

Tags: flutter

I use stack to place images, my back image is drawn on top of the other one, how can i fix the posterpath to be on top, also top image doesn't round the edges:

```
 return Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned(
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 390 / 220,
        child: ColorFiltered(
          colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
            Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
            BlendMode.dstATop,
          ),
          child: backdropPath != null
              ? Image.network(ImageDownloader.imageUrl(backdropPath))
          : Image.asset(AppImages.noImageBig),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 110.0),
          child: Container(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
            ),
            height: 212.0,
            width: 174.0,
            child: posterPath != null
                ? Image.network(ImageDownloader.imageUrl(posterPath))
            : Image.asset(AppImages.noImageBig),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering of children in a `Stack` is determined by their order in the source code - later items in the list are drawn on top. If you want to switch the z-order of the two children, swap them in the source code.

For your second question, you can achieve "rounded corner" with `ClipRRect` widget.

Comment: it works if i deleted ColorFiltered, but i lose the needed transparency effect. ClipRRect works as it should, thx.

Comment: how can i do transparency effect to backdropPath image?

Comment: @srzh what's "transparency effect"? Do you mean `Opacity` widget?

Comment: i used ColorFiltered, but i can't use it anymore, because the image is superimposed on one another in stack

Comment: @srzh Have you tried the `Opacity` widget?